# TwoWayView in TwoWayView onItemClick not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 TwoWayView in each other. The inner is TWB the outer is TWA.

The problem is that TWA is need to be clickable but the onitemclick function only runs at onitemlongclick event.

TWA's holder xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView

            android:id="@+id/innerView"
            android:focusable="false"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

in TWA's adapter I tried to disable all clickable and focusable things to TWB:

```
        viewHolder.innerView.setAdapter(innerListAdapters.get(position));
        viewHolder.innerView.setClickable(false);
        viewHolder.innerView.setLongClickable(false);
        viewHolder.innerView.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.innerView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        viewHolder.innerView.setOnItemClickListener(null);
        viewHolder.innerView.setOnItemLongClickListener(null);
        viewHolder.innerView.setOnTouchListener(null);
        viewHolder.innerView.setChoiceMode(TwoWayView.ChoiceMode.NONE);
        viewHolder.innerView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

And this is how i try to set the onItemClick and onItemLongClick to TWA:

```
friendList.setAdapter(new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), friends));
        friendList.setLongClickable(true);
        friendList.setClickable(true);
        friendList.setItemMargin(10);

        //final FriendsAdapter adapter = (FriendsAdapter) friendList.getAdapter();
        friendList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                utils.sendToLog("l   " + l + "");

                friendListItemClicked(i);

            }
        });

        friendList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                friendListItemLongClicked(i);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you tried with focusable=true?

Comment: Do you have any other layout except for the listview in your layout?

Comment: no just the listview in a relative layout

Comment: why do yo need this `viewHolder.innerView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);`? Can you try commenting this out and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I added them one by one thinking that it might be helpfull... i commented it out but nothing happended.

Comment: Try something different. Firstly see if you use this layout as your activity layout the onClick method will work. Also try a very simple row layout for your listview (like just one TextView) and then see if onItemClick is being called. This way we can figure out whether the issue from the TwoWayLayout is from the ListVew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it :)

The problem was that the innerView made the onClick event. So I had to bind my normal onItemClick with the inner one. Like simulate TWA's item in TWB.

Here is the code for the future :)

```
 viewHolder.innerView.setDescendantFocusability(RelativeLayout.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

        {
            final AdapterView fParent = (AdapterView) parent;
            final View fView = rowView;
            final int fInt = position;
            final long fLong = rowView.getId();

            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener cross = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    listener.onItemClick(fParent,fView, fInt, fLong);
                }
            };
            viewHolder.innerView.setOnItemClickListener(cross);
        }
```